# MOSFET h-side turn on

Tags: transistors, mosfet, high-side

I implement following circuit

[image]

I used 12v alarm instead of led at high side.

I used two 5.6k Ω resistor (blue) at place of Rg and 330 Ω resistor in place of R1

I used the same IRF630 n-channel mosfet

45 white row is + 12V

62 orange row is 12V GND

17 yellow row is +5 V

Alarm doesn't ring

[image]

I tested alarm at series 12 V circuit with 330 Ohm resistor without mosfet and it ring properly

Edit:
measured voltages at leads:

Vds: 1.1V

Vgs: 0 V

Edit:

if I connect gate to +12 V alarm rings, at such configuration gate-source is 11.8 V

Comment: The 12 V alarm probably doesn't want a resistor in series with it.  But no way to know unless you link to the datasheet for the alarm.

Comment: I tested alarm at series12 V circuit with 330 Ohm resistor without mosfet and it ring properly

Comment: Are you really using an IRF630 and driving with 5 V? The threshold can be as high as 4 V, so you may not be turning the FET on hard enough.  Measure the drain voltage while you're trying to turn the FET on and see what you get.

Comment: It looks okay (typically, you've not really got enough gate voltage for that MOSFET to switch fully on worst case). Maybe one of your jumper wires is open. Measure the two voltage at the MOSFET gate and drain relative to the source, right at the TO-220 leads, and tell us what readings you get.

Comment: drain-source: 1.1V
gate-source: 0 V

Comment: Ah, if you have 1.1 V drain-to-source with 0 V gate-to-source your FET is broken.

Comment: if I connect gate to +12 V alarm rings,  
at such configuration gate-source is 11.8 V

Comment: With 0 V Vgs your drain should be 12 V, so if it's not, it indicates FET damage.  If you want to switch the load with a 5 V gate drive, you should choose a logic-level FET.  The fact that it works when you drive the gate to 12 V shows that the 5 V drive isn't sufficient.

Comment: I looked at docs and I can read that drive voltage is 10V,

Comment: @JakubKutrzeba: Connect the buzzer directly across 12 volts. Measure the current. Report back to us. Otherwise provide the link to the datasheet as requested in other comments.

Comment: Connection between 5 V GND and 12 V GND is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Connection between 5 V GND and 12 V GND was missing